# How to use FIND_IN_SET with select statement in symfony 5.1?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

symfony version: 5.1

There is a sql statement and work in command:

```
SELECT 
    p.sn as pid, 
    p.title as title, 
    pc.title as categoryName 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', pa.`meta_key`, pa.`meta_value`) order by a.`sort_by` asc) as filters
FROM `product` as p 
LEFT JOIN `product_category` as pc on pc.id = p.`category_id` 
LEFT JOIN `product_model` as pm on p.`model_id` = pm.id 
LEFT JOIN `brand` as b on b.id = p.brand_id 
LEFT JOIN `product_attribute` as pa on pa.`product_id` = p.id 
LEFT JOIN `attribute` as a on pa.`attribute_id` = a.id 
WHERE p.status = 1 and a.`search_enable` = 1 and pa.`attribute_id` is not null 
    and FIND_IN_SET('name=test', (
        SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', pa2.`meta_key`, pa2.`meta_value`)) 
        FROM `product_attribute` as pa2 
        LEFT JOIN `attribute` as a2 on a2.`id` = pa2.`attribute_id` 
        WHERE pa2.`product_id` = p.`id` and a2.`search_enable` = 1 
        GROUP BY pa2.`product_id`
    )) and FIND_IN_SET('age=18', (
        SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', pa2.`meta_key`, pa2.`meta_value`)) 
        FROM `product_attribute` as pa2 
        LEFT JOIN `attribute` as a2 on a2.`id` = pa2.`attribute_id` 
        WHERE pa2.`product_id` = p.`id` and a2.`search_enable` = 1 
        GROUP BY pa2.`product_id`
    ))
GROUP BY p.`id`;
```

But the function of FIND_IN_SET is not working in doctrine query.

```
$query->andWhere("FIND_IN_SET('age=18', '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', pa2.metaKey, pa2.metaKey)) FROM ProductAttribute as pa2 LEFT JOIN Attribute as a2 on a2.id = pa2.attribute WHERE pa2.product = p.id and a2.searchEnable = 1 GROUP BY pa2.product)')");
```

I get error message:

```
PHP message: [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 657: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '='"
```

If I change the find_in_set statement remove the single quotes wit select statement:

```
$query->andWhere("FIND_IN_SET('age=18', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', pa2.metaKey, pa2.metaKey)) FROM ProductAttribute as pa2 LEFT JOIN Attribute as a2 on a2.id = pa2.attribute WHERE pa2.product = p.id and a2.searchEnable = 1 GROUP BY pa2.product)");
```

I got this error message:

```
PHP message: [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 625: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'"
```

How to use the FIND_IN_SET with select statement?

About the relationship of table:

```
1, product and product_category are manyToOne;
2, product and product_model are manyToOne;
3, product and brand are manyToOne;
4, product and product_attribute are oneToMany;
5, product_attribute and attribute are ManyToOne;
```

The product has many attributes that a part of it will be filtered when user search product with keywords.

So, I want to a filter function same as amazon that user can click the option of filter to get a new list of products from search result.

[image]

Comment: Your FIND_IN_SET must be rewrited to INNER JOIN or NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Thanks for your help and solved it now. save my time.